# spark job running with Peak Execution Memory Onheap=0.0B

Tags: apache-spark

Peak Execution Memory Onheap for Spark cluster is showing 0.0B which is odd. There is another cluster for which it is otherway Offheap=0.0B and Onheap is between 512MB to 1GB. It is not clear why Onheap memory is 0.0B , trying to find if there are any spark settings to be added to cluster. Please assist
[image]